# Solving and graphing all values of $z$.

Tags: complex-numbers

> **Question:** Find and graph all values of $z$ such that $$|z-3|=|z+2i|\tag1$$

---

I'm not sure how to find $z$. Here's my attempt:

---

Let $z=a+bi$. Plugging that into $(1)$ gives us $$|a+bi-3|=|a+bi+2i|\tag2$$
And using the magnitude definition, we have $$\sqrt{(a-3)^2+b^2}=\sqrt{a^2+(2+b)^2}\tag3$$
Squaring both sides and moving all the constants to one side, we get the linear equation $$6a+4b=5$$
Which takes care of the graphing part. But I'm not sure how to find the value of $z$ at this point.

---

**EDIT:** The book states the answer as $5$. How did they get $5$??

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Cz%E2%88%923%7C%3D%7Cz%2B2i%7C

Comment: @superbjhon The link you give makes no sense. Either WA cannot do this calculation or else something else must be fed to it. Anyway, it doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say it in words and perhaps some hidden knowledge of geometry will kick in: the set of all complex numbers (=points in the plane) that fulfill $\;|z-3|=|z+2i|\;$ is the set of all points in the plane whose distance from $\;3\;$ equals their distance from $\;-2i\;$ ...some bell ringing?

> This is just the perpendicualr bisector of the segment of line joining the points $\;3\,,\,\,-2i\;$ in the complex plane.

**Added on request**: Putting $\;z=x+iy\;,\;\;x,y\in\Bbb R\;$ , we get:

$$|z-3|^2=|z+2i|^2\implies(x-3)^2+y^2=x^2+(y+2)^2\implies$$

$$-6x+9=4y+4\implies\;\;\ell:\; 6x+4y-5=0$$

The above is a straight line with slope equal to $\;m=-\frac32\;$ . Observe that the slope between $\;3\sim(3,0)\;$ and $\;2i\sim (0,-2)\;$ (here we identify complex numbers with points in the plane, as usual) is $\;\cfrac{0-(-2)}{3-0}=\cfrac23\;$  , so $\;\cfrac23\cdot m=-1\;$ and $\;\ell\;$ indeed is perpendicular to the line segment whose extremes are $\;(3,0),\,(0,-2)\;$, as expected.

Finally, to see $\;\ell\;$ is a bisector of the line segment, we show the distance of iether extreme point to the line is the same:

$$\begin{align*}&(3,0)\;\text{from}\;\ell:\;\;\frac{|6\cdot3+4\cdot0-5|}{\sqrt{6^2+4^2}}=\frac{13}{\sqrt{52}}=\frac{\sqrt{13}}2\\{}\\
&(0,-2)\;\text{from}\;\ell:\;\;\frac{|6\cdot0+4\cdot(-2)-5|}{\sqrt{6^2+4^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{13}}2\end{align*}$$

Comment: Do you know of an algebraic way? Like substituting $z$ with $a+bi$, then isolating $z$ to find what $z$ equals?

Comment: @Frank I added some stuff to my answer, to make it algebraic.

Answer (score 0):

Geometrically, it is the set of points equidistant from the images $A$ and $B$ of  $-2i$  and $3$, i.e. the perpendicular bisector of the segment $[AB]$.

So we have to find:

1) the affix of the middle point $I$ of the segment: $\;z_I=\dfrac32+2i$.

2) a complex number $z_0$ with image orthogonal to $[AB]$. As the affix of $\overrightarrow{AB}$ is $3+2i$, $z_0=2-3i$ is a solution.

Hence the values of $z$ we seek is
$$z=\dfrac32+2i+t(2-3i)=\dfrac32+2t+(2-3t)i\qquad(t\in\mathbf R).$$